# Detect unsupported browser version and show specific div with message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, browser-detection

I have a chat bot in my website it need latest version of browsers to work perfectly so I need to show a message to user saying "Please update your browser to latest version". I don't want to use third party plugin.  How can i show a div if the user is using unsupported version of browsers using this js code

Html

```
<div id="printVer"></div>
```

JS

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem,
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
document.getElementById('printVer').innerHTML=navigator.sayswho
```

Comment: userAgent "sniffing" is not considered accurate - preferred option is to use feature detection ... think to yourself, what "new" features do I use ... check for them ... do appropriate actions if not detected

Comment: Have a read of this as to why useragent is a fallacy: https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection

Comment: It's also very easy to change your useragent in the browser.  And what happens when a brand new "super-duper-browser" comes along that you've haven't considered but works with your code but your page stupidly says "update to latest version" - but I have the "latest" version, are you going to update your code every week?

Comment: @freedomn-m  we are mainly considering Chrome(above 60), firefox (above 50) and IE (11). Is it easy to detect version and show message using modenizr ? Am pretty new at modenizr that's am asking. Thanks

Comment: No, you're missing the whole concept.  You're saying "this only works in browser x v.n so I need to check for x v.n" - when in actuality your code "only works because browser x v.n has feature A" - so you instead need to "check for feature A" and then it doesn't matter what browser it is because it has the feature you want/need.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry for misleading, I said like "this works better in browser with > X version". I don't want check the features of browser and I don't want implement a whole modernizr code for small feature.  Fortunately i found a solution, I know that is not a best practice . Check my answer. thank you for your timely support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
navigator.sayswho = ( function () {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, tem,
        M = ua.match( /(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i ) || [];
    if ( /trident/i.test( M[1] ) ) {
        tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec( ua ) || [];
        return 'IE ' + ( tem[1] || '' );
    }
    if ( M[1] === 'Chrome' ) {
        tem = ua.match( /\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/ );
        if ( tem != null ) return tem.slice( 1 ).join( ' ' ).replace( 'OPR', 'Opera' );
    }
    M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if ( ( tem = ua.match( /version\/(\d+)/i ) ) != null ) M.splice( 1, 1, tem[1] );
    return M.join( ' ' );
} )();
//document.getElementById('printVer').innerHTML=navigator.sayswho
var str = navigator.sayswho;
var browser = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( " " ) );
var version = str.substring( str.indexOf( " " ) );
version = version.trim();
version = parseInt( version );
console.log( browser );
console.log( version );

if ( ( browser == "Chrome" && version < 70 ) || ( browser == "Firefox" && version < 53 ) || ( browser == "Safari" && version < 5 ) || ( browser == "IE" && version < 11 ) || ( browser == "Opera" && version < 52 ) ) {
    $( '#printVer' ).show();
}
else {
    $( '#printVer' ).hide();
}
```

Comment: is there any javascript package to show alert when the browser is outdated version or unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if it's anything other than support browsers, you might want to use jQuery's browser detection, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// check if browser is IE6 (when IE) or not FF6 (when FF)
if (($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) == '6')
    || ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) != '3')) {
        $('#browserWarning').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `jquery's $.browser was deprecated in 2009 and removed in 2013. [...]` (from a [now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044656/6296561) attempting to reply to this)

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm not checking OS e.g. mobile or bla bla. Try this for Browser version ==>

```
( function ( window ) {
    //Get Browser Type
    var browser = {
        /** Define Browser Type*/
        type:/** Whether we are using a IE Browser or not. */
        typeof ( window.attachEvent ) === 'function' && !( Object.prototype.toString.call( window.opera ) == '[object Opera]' )
            ? 'IE'
            /** Whether we are using a Opera Browser or not. */
            : ( Object.prototype.toString.call( window.opera ) == '[object Opera]' || navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'Opera Mini' ) > -1 )
                ? 'Opera'
                /** Whether we are using a WebKit Type Browser or not. */
                : ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'AppleWebKit/' ) > -1 )
                    ? 'WebKit'
                    /** Whether we are using a Gecko Type Browser or not. */
                    : ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'Gecko' ) > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf( 'KHTML' ) === -1 )
                        ? 'Gecko'
                        /** Whether we are using a Apple Browser or not. */
                        : ( /Apple.*Mobile/.test( navigator.userAgent ) )
                            ? 'MobileSafari'
                            : undefined
    };
    //Get Browser Version
    browser.version = function () {
        let ua; ua = navigator.userAgent;
        return this.type === 'Gecko' ? /** Whether this browser type is Gecko*/function ( a ) {
            let rv = -1, re = new RegExp( "rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})" );
            re.exec( ua ) !== null ? rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 ) : '';
            if ( ua.indexOf( 'Firefox/' ) > 0 ) { a.name = 'Firefox'; return rv; }
            if ( ua.indexOf( 'Trident/' ) > 0 ) {/** IE > 10*/a.name = 'IE'; return rv; }
            return rv;
        }( this ) : this.type === 'WebKit' ?/** Whether this browser type is WebKit*/ function ( a, b ) {
            let rv = -1, re;
            re = ua.match( /Opera|OPR\/([0-9]+)\./ );
            if ( null !== re ) {
                rv = parseInt( re[1], 10 ); a.name = 'Opera';
                return rv;
            }
            re = ua.match( /Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./ );
            if ( null !== re ) {
                rv = parseInt( re[2], 10 ); a.name = 'Chrome';
                return rv;
            }
            re = /AppleWebKit\/([\d.]+)/.exec( navigator.userAgent );
            if ( null !== re ) {
                rv = parseFloat( re[1] ); a.name = 'Safari';
                return rv;
            }
            return rv;
        }( this ) : this.type === 'IE' ?/** Whether this browser type is IE (IE version < 9)*/ function ( a ) {
            let rv = -1, re;
            re = new RegExp( "MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})" );
            return re.exec( ua ) !== null ? ( rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 ), a.name = 'IE', rv ) : rv;
        }( this ) : this.type === 'Opera' ?/** Whether this browser type is Opera*/ function ( a ) {
            let rv = -1;
            try {
                rv = navigator.userAgent.match( /Version\/([1-9]+\.[0-9]{2})/ )[1]; a.name = 'Opera';
                return rv;
            } catch ( ex ) {
                return rv;
            }
        }( this ) : /** Undefined browser type define*/ -1;
    }.call( browser );

    window.browser = browser;

}( window ) );
```

Check your condition ==>

```
if ( ( browser.name === 'Chrome' && browser.version <= 60 )
    || ( browser.name === 'IE' && browser.version < 11 )
    || ( browser.name === 'Firefox' && browser.version <= 50 ) ) {
    // Not Supported
} else {
    //Supported or Undefined Browser
}
```